# Error facing while parsing xml for special character

Tags: pandas, xml, parsing

For my project, I need to parse an XML file with special characters and can't escape them. While trying with elementree, I am facing the following error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\Palash\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    etree = et.parse('dblp.xml')
  File "C:\Users\Palash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1229, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Palash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 580, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &ouml;: line 67, column 20
```

The code I'm using is :

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
def intr_docs(xml_doc):
    attr = xml_doc.attrib

    for xml in xml_doc.itrer('document'):
        doc_dict = attr.copy()
        doc_dict.update(xml.attrib)
        doc_dict['data'] = xml.text

        yield doc_dict

etree = et.parse('dblp.xml') #The line it shows the problem
doc_df = pd.DataFrame(list(intr_docs(etree.getroot())))

print(doc_df)
```

And an example content of the XML file: `gist.github.com/Roy101/6ca68420498109c5837940532c18c742`

Comment: Specify which line produces the error. Try to make a [reprex]

Comment: Please provide example content of `dblp.xml` that reproduces the problem

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Roy101/6ca68420498109c5837940532c18c742

This is a sample of my xml file . My actual file is too large to share.(4gb)

Answer (score 0):

If it contains `&ouml;` and `&ouml;` hasn't been declared in the DTD then it's not well-formed XML so any XML parser is going to reject it.

You need to modify the XML file to reference a DTD that declares this entity - possibly the XHTML DTD if your document is actually XHTML.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Roy101/6ca68420498109c5837940532c18c742

This is a sample of my xml file . My actual file is too large to share.(4gb)

Comment: What's in the DTD dblp.dtd? My guess is it declares these entities, which means you just need to use an XML parser that reads and uses the DTD. No idea whether such a thing exists in pandas, but perhaps you could do an identity transform on the document in some other environment to expand the entities.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code might help you solve the problem.
It actually is the problem of not defining the special character entity in the code before parsing the xml.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
def intr_docs(xml_doc):
    attr = xml_doc.attrib

    for xml in xml_doc.itrer('document'):
        doc_dict = attr.copy()
        doc_dict.update(xml.attrib)
        doc_dict['data'] = xml.text

        yield doc_dict


parser = et.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity['ouml'] = 'ö'

etree = et.parse('dblp.xml', parser=parser)
doc_df = pd.DataFrame(list(intr_docs(etree.getroot())))

print(doc_df)
```

Comment: it doesnt work. Try this gist to read gist.github.com/Roy101/6ca68420498109c5837940532c18c742